# ActiveX Error while initializing Collection object

Tags: vba

I have defined my variable as below:

```
Dim var1 As New Collection
```

and initialized the same as below:

```
set var1 = New Collection
```

I am getting error

> ActiveX can not create object

at above line. I am able to initialize all the other objects such as Dictionary etc.

Answer (score 0):

The first line - `Dim var1 as New Collection` defines and initializes the collection. Thus the set is not needed, (but in general, it should be working, although not needed). Try this, if the error is in the `Set` line, it should be working:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myVar As New Collection
    myVar.Add 123
    myVar.Add 234
    Dim counter As Long
    For counter = 1 To myVar.Count
        Debug.Print myVar(counter)
    Next

End Sub
```

Judging from the error, there could be some a missing library in the VBA file. Take a look at the Extras>Libraries, probably there is something MISSING, which is checked:

[image]

If this is the case, simply remove the MISSING: check.

Comment: Thanks Vityata for your reply!!! It didn't work the way you suggested. All the other objects are working fine such as Dictionary etc but just getting error in "Collection" object only. Does "Collection" object behave any differently?

Comment: @Anu - this is rather strange actually. I have never seen any difference so far.